# HABTM or Has Many Through Model design in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am designing a certification model for the following purpose.  A user will have a set of certifications say [A,B,C,D].  An article will have a set of certifications as well, say [B,D].  I want to be able to find articles where their certifications are some subset (read: any subset) of a user's certifications.  That is, if the article were to have certs [A,B,E] it would not be returned but if it had [A] or [A,D] or whatever it would return fine. Really the way I envision doing it is taking the user.certs intersection with art.certs and ensuring the resulting set equals art.certs.size. I implemented this as a HABTM as I dont really need to access the join object, but am having trouble working out the logic.  I ended up doing something like this:

```
@certs = @user.certifications.collect{|c| c.id}
Article.all(:joins=>:certifications, 
         :group=>Article.attributes_for_sql, 
         :select=>'articles.*', 
         :conditions => ['certifications.id in (?)', @certs], 
         :having=> "count(articles.id)=(select (count(article_id)) from articles_certifications where article_id = articles.id group by article_id)")
```

This seems to work but is exceedingly ugly.

In any case, how should I design this relationship to make this as easy as possible and what would an example solution look like?

Thanks for any help, I have really been banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: Why HABTM? Which two models have a many-to-many relationship? I only see two one-to-many relationships where you want to make your intersection.

Comment: Also, your first line could be probably rewritten as:
    @certs = @user.certifications.all(:select => "id")
This way, you're only pulling back one field from the database, not whole objects.

Comment: Well certifications are static.. So there are like 20 or so.  Thus, there are lots of users who have the finance certification, and the finance certification will thus have lots of users attached to it so calling Certification.find_by_name('finance').users will get you all the users that have it.  The same is true for articles.  If you call @article.certifications you will get all the certs and if you call @cert.articles you will get all the articles that require that cert.  Edit:  I am open to other suggestions of course.

Comment: OK, makes sense. This part is a bit confusing: "I want to be able to find articles where their certifications are some subset (read: any subset) of a user's articles."

The user is also adjoined to articles?

Comment: Ah, my fault.  That should be certifications.  Changed it in the original q.  Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, having clarified the situation a bit, here's my official attempt at an answer, :D

From what I gather, you want articles with all the certifications the user has. The certifications are the same record across models so IDs should work fine.

Why not try a simple IN statement, like this:

```
@user_certs = @user.certifications.all(:select => "id")
Article.all(:conditions => ["certification_id IN ?", @user_certs])
```

This should pull back any article that has the same certification as the user you're looking at.

I hope I've grokked your question.

Comment: Hmm. This oversimplifies it.  An article should only be returned if the User possesses ALL the certs that the Article has, not just ANY ONE.  In addition, Articles are connected to certifications via HABTM (i.e. a join table), so certification_id is not a valid column.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant the join table, not articles.

Comment: See the solution above.  That is a working solution, it is just horribly gross.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to drop from query all articles which have certificates the user doesn't have. The SQL is pretty straitforward:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL
    FROM articles_certificates ac
    WHERE ac.article_id = a.id AND ac.certificate_id NOT IN
        (SELECT cu.certificate_id
        FROM certificates_users cu INNER JOIN users u ON cu.user_id = u.id
        WHERE u.id = #{user_id})
    )
```

I'm not an expert in ActiveRelations query, so my query resembles my SQL very much :), sorry

```
Article.joins(:certificates).
    all(:conditions => "NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM articles_certificates WHERE articles_certificates.certificate_id NOT IN ? AND articles.id = articles_certificates.article_id)", #{user.certificates})
```